# How to make it so D3 Force Directed Graph generates nodes in same position each time

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, coordinates

When I call d3.start() on a d3.js force directed I generate a graph with nodes and edges in particular locations. However, when I call start again with the same data, the positioning of the nodes is different than previously. Is there a way to make it so that nodes are positioned in the same positions each time?

Do I absolutely set the first nodes position, and then somehow position relatively to that first nodes position each time?Thanks.

My code for building the d3-force graph is boilerplate.

And following my collection of data from my internal json and creating the node and link objects I call

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var n = node.size();
    node.forEach(function(d, i) {
      d.x = d.y = width / n * i;
    });
    console.log(node);
    setTimeout(function(){
      force.start();
      for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) force.tick();
      force.stop();
    },300);
},100);
```

where node is the array of circle objects I use for nodes...Also it does not seem like the nodes are initializing along the diagonal for when I first call start. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the d3 documentation, aligning your nodes along a diagonal line, will make the force directed algorithm balance the nodes positions with the least number of iterations in most cases.

I use it this way and I get consistent positions every time I use the same data set.

> The number of iterations depends on the graph size and complexity. The choice of initial positions can also have a dramatic impact on how quickly the graph converges on a good solution. For example, here the nodes are arranged along the diagonal:

```
var n = nodes.length;
nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.x = d.y = width / n * i;
});
```

From: 
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout

This means that setting your nodes' positions is redundant. Let the force directed sort all the positions for you, by calling *.start()* after you've done something similar to the code above.

Comment: Hi, I've added this code to my code and still produce varying results each time.It doesn't seem that the nodes initialize along the diagonal, so I am still confused. I have attached the new code I have added above. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, could you also show the code where you initialized the force behavior and feed it with the nodes and links? I suspect the issue might lie there

Comment: @user3014093 Thanks for approving my answer, but I'd still like to see what went wrong if possible.

Comment: My charge was set to a very high value which caused a lot of additional randomness. So when I corrected that the positioning became very similar with each generation of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a simple way to layout according to the first position, resume the `x` and `y` before next force layout

```
data.forEach((e)=>{
  e.x = e.firstX
  e.y = e.firstY
})

layout(data)
```